# Load HTML, JS, CSS bundles locally from device in IOS app not working

Tags: android, ios, swift, ionic-framework, capacitor

How can I load a mobile website, developed using Ionic, into an existing iOS app upon a button click? I'm encountering an issue where the WebView is not functioning properly with locally stored files on the device's bundle. Only URLs seem to be working with the WebView.

I'm facing an issue with WebView where locally stored files, particularly React(next static export) bundles from Ionic, aren't loading correctly. While a simple HTML page with a JS script does work, React bundles fail to load. I'm aiming to achieve the same functionality how ionic works in a WebView with local files. So I can create it as a Pod to install it in existing IOS app.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Create a WKWebView
        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds)
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        
        // Add the WKWebView to the view hierarchy
        view.addSubview(webView)
        
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "out") {
                webView.load( URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) )
            }
    }
}
```

Folder Structre:

[image]

Does anyone have insights or suggestions on how to make local bundles work with WebView in this scenario? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have a folder named 'out' on top of the Xcode project folder?  How do you deliver it with the binary package?

Comment: Shouldn't the out guy be inside of the Xcode project folder?

Comment: @ElTomato I am getting the path correctly but js files not loading in HTML. This is the path and i can see out folder contents there. ```file:///Users/*******/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3AB11E45-1F78-468B-8B34-7B88E5F84A3A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5D9DE0EE-58BB-4382-96C5-D1D20DD1F22F/feb.app/out/index.html```

Comment: I see.  Have you tried loading the file asynchronously?

Comment: @ElTomato I have tried this way. ```<script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/index-60c17b2cbb377adc.js" async="" crossorigin=""></script>``` But it is same.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. you use [Ionic portals](https://ionic.io/portals) for this functionality.

Comment: I know we can use ionic portals or MF but this is for an existing ios project. And we prefer not to change existing ios project to ionic. Thanks for your suggestions.